# How to create an email with dynamic content (i.e. customer's air mile points)

Tags: sql-server, outlook, sql-server-2012

I am in need of sending internal newsletters which include Sales people's target vs actual. I'm hoping to automate this as much as possible. I need their first name, last name and table that includes target attainments for the accounts they manage,  all pulled based on the query using MSSQL (2012-ENT).

I'm thinking it's doable since I always receive newsletters from airlines that includes my airmile# and points attained to date.

I have the query, I have the content, but I cannot find out how I can merge them together dynamically and automate for individual sales people.

I appreciate any help.

thanks,

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee you that airlines don't have some person sending marketing emails from Outlook. There are whole companies built around email marketing trategies. Just Google "Email Marketing Companies."

Comment: Hi Tim, I appreciate your help, but again this is for internal newsletter and we don't have budget to engage external agencies, I am hoping to develop this in-house using the current technologies that we have.

Comment: Perhaps this link will help: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-send-personalized-e-mail-messages-to-your-e-mail-address-list-HA010109162.aspx. But my downvote stays because this question belongs on SuperUser (http://superuser.com), not StackOverflow. The title is also misleading. Are you or aren't you dealing with customers and airline mile points?

Answer (score 1):

1. In SSMS, perform your SQL query to get the Name, Email Address, Sales Target, and Actual Sales.
2. Select all the rows in the results grid by clicking in the upper left corner where the header row and header column interset.
3. Copy that to the clipboard.
4. Open Excel and paste into a new document.
5. Follow the instructions on [this web page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-send-personalized-e-mail-messages-to-your-e-mail-address-list-HA010109162.aspx).
6. ????
7. Profit!!!!